# ef code first one-to-one relationship with foreign key in model that is not also primary key

Tags: breeze

it's my understanding that ef code first does not support one to one relationships with an explicit foreign key on the dependent side that is NOT also the primary key... it's also my understanding that in order for breeze navigation properties to work, there MUST be a foreign key on the dependent side... so my question then is, is it correct to assume then that there's no way to get a one to one relationship with an explicit foreign key that is not also the primary key to work in breeze? if so, are there any workarounds? if not, how would i need to set up the metadata? we actually programatically generate our metadata following the nodb sample... is there any way through code to set up this type of navigation property? assume that we will still have a foreign key on the dependent side, only that it will be ignored by EF... thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. I'm pretty certain the answer is "No".

Take a look at this example from ["metadata by hand"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-by-hand). It describes the navigation from the dependent `Product` to it's principal `Category`.

```
navigationProperties: {
        category: {
            entityTypeName: "Category",
            associationName: "Product_Category",
            foreignKeyNames: ["categoryID"]
        },
```

Notice that it identifies the FK property `categoryID` but is silent about the property on the principal side that the FK value must match.

That silence speaks volumes. Clearly "it goes without saying" that the matching property on the principal is the principle entity's key.

EF has sound Entity Data Modeling reasons for imposing this constraint (darned if I can remember what they are). Apparently Breeze follows suit.